# How can I see the console output from an assertion in Bixby story testing?

Tags: bixby, bixbystudio

Is it possible to log console output and see what is going on when putting in assertions? I am seeing the desired behavior (the correct prompt shows up) of my capsule, however the assertion that checks for a prompt is failing and I can't really find any way to debug these assertions.

Also, I'm kind of new to StackOverflow so I could make this question more specific to my issue if that is better. I figured it would be best to start with a general question like this that would be useful to a wider audience!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Story Assertions](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/dev-guide/developers/testing.stories_assertions) feature is still in *preview*. Currently there is no great way to debug assertions. Rest assured we are working to stabilize the feature and provide full debug tooling.

P.S. I work on the Bixby Developer Studio team